# How is Crystal Kyber CPA-secure algorithms converted into a CCA-secure algorithm

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, chosen-plaintext-attack, chosen-ciphertext-attack, kyber

In Crystal Kyber [specification](https://pq-crystals.org/kyber/data/kyber-specification-round3-20210804.pdf), page no10, there are 3 algorithms namely **KYBER.CCAKEM** for making the *CPA-secure* Kyber into *CCA-secure* one.

Q1: How is the shared key ***K*** being generated in **KYBER.CCAKEM.Enc** & **KYBER.CCAKEM.Enc** related to the *CPA-secure* algorithms ?

Q2: Is the shared key ***K*** used as input parameter of sorts, for the CPA-secure algorithm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A1: $K$ is the result of applying a key derivation function to the hash of an output of   the `KYBER.CPAPKE.Enc()` function concatenated with a hash of the message and public key. This can be seen on line 5 of the `Kyber.CCAKEM.Enc()` function specification (here $c$ is the output of `KYBER.CPAPKE.Enc()` per line 4). In `KYBER.CCAKEM.Dec()` the $K$ value returned is either the same as the value returned in `KYBER.CCAKEM.Enc()` or a fake value that is published if the $c$ is deemed to have been potentially maliciously generated.

A2: No, but the input $r$ to `KYBER.CPAPKE.Enc()` is now the output of a hash of the message and public key (see lines 3 and 4 of `KYBER.CCAKEM.Enc()`) rather than an arbitrary value.

The issue here is that (module) Learning with Errors schemes are prone to decryption failures and an adversary can gain information about private values based on these failures. In particular, if a CCA adversary maliciously crafts secret vectors and error values with larger values than the `KYBER.CPAPKE.Enc()` process permits, then failures are more likely to occur. The process in `KYBER.CCAKEM.Enc()` and `KYBER.CCAKEM.Dec()` (a variant of the a [Fujisaki-Okamoto transform](https://cs.uni-paderborn.de/fileadmin/informatik/fg/cuk/Lehre/Abschlussarbeiten/Bachelorarbeiten/2014/BA_Lippert_FOT_final.pdf)) ensures that the random secret and error values were legitimately created and checked to be legitimate as part of the decryption process.